# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server

Tags: php, smtp

I use this code and I get an SMTP error. Anyone know what may cause it? My hosting provider says the SMTP ports are open. I have tried using on a local server and it works.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
 
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail->Username = "example@hotmail.com";
$mail->Password = "pass";
$mail->Port = 587;



$mail->setFrom("example@hotmail.com", "User");
$mail->addAddress("example@hotmail.com", "User");

$mail->Subject = $name; 
$mail->Body = "Email: $email \nPhone: $subject \n\n$message";



$mail->send();

header("Location: sent.php");
```

Comment: Login to the server and test via `telnet smtp.office365.com 587` if the connection does open. If yes, it is not a firewall/connection problem.

Comment: I tried it and it says the ports aren't open even though my hosting provider told me they were. What should I do to debug it?

Comment: Try the same from your local computer and see if there is a difference. I tested from my machine and it works. https://pastebin.com/Fvfhxdkk You should see a similar output. If not, the ports are *NOT* open. Maybe the hoster forbids to prevent spamming.

Comment: I tried the same from my VPS and it connected without any problems.